# How to avoid duplicating code in actions with ReduxThunk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

How to avoid duplicating the same constance in actions like that? Thanks!

```
export const createLabelAction = (name, color) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const authorization = getState().get('authorization').authorization;
        const repositoryOwner = getState().get('repositoryLoader').repositoryOwner;
        const selectedRepository = getState().get('repositoryLoader').selectedRepository;
        const updateInProcess = getState().get('repoLabels').updateInProcess;
        return api.createLabel(authorization, repositoryOwner, selectedRepository, name, color)
            .then(result => {
                //  Status: 201 Created
                if(result.status === 201) {
                    //  if updating not processing
                    if (!updateInProcess) {
                        dispatch(fetchListLabelsForRepositoryAction(repositoryOwner, selectedRepository));
                    }
               }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
}

export const updateLabelAction = (labelUrl, newName, newColor) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const authorization = getState().get('authorization').authorization;
        const repositoryOwner = getState().get('repositoryLoader').repositoryOwner;
        const selectedRepository = getState().get('repositoryLoader').selectedRepository;
        const updateInProcess = getState().get('repoLabels').updateInProcess;
        return api.updateLabel(authorization, labelUrl, newName, newColor)
            .then(result => {
                //  Status: 200 OK
                if(result.status === 200) {
                    //  if updating not processing
                    if (!updateInProcess) {
                        dispatch(fetchListLabelsForRepositoryAction(repositoryOwner, selectedRepository));

                    }
                }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

I have more than two functions like that, it's hard. If I change selectors. I must change all constance in actions. Can I put them in one place?

Comment: Why not create one function that you pass 'getState' as an argument and that returns the required values (which you now have as constants) as properties of an object?

Comment: @BjörnBoxstart great, it works. Thanks!

Comment: Adding on to @BjörnBoxstart:  If you're using this frequently you might want to look into using [Reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect), which is made for this exact purpose while also allows you to cache the results of such a function if you intend to use it repeatedly.